# Reset Camon ImageClass MF632Cdw to Factory setting

Tags: restore

I have been asked to come it to troublshoot a small businesses Canon ImageClass MF632Cdw
No one seems to know the user ID and password that was set up on it.

I am wanting to set the printer back to factory settings. How can I do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As a possible quick fix, have you tried the default username and password for the Canon?

It should be

User: 7654321

PW: 7654321

Answer (score 0):

After hours trying to resolve an issue where although connected to wifi, the printer showed offline and therefore could not print. I was trying to do a manufacture reset and couldn't. I was able to resolve the issue in a few minutes after talking with client services at canon 1-800-OK-CANON. 
The issue was with the IP address emitted by my router (internet was working just fine). 
1- unplug modem and ruter and wait 30 sec. before re-plugging
2-reconfigure the wireless settings on the printer
3- find the IPV4 ip adresse on the printer (monitor status, network information)
4-enter this IP address as if it were a web page on your internet browser.. if it connects you to a web page related to the printer you are all set, try printing all should work.to